# drag and drop does not work using Selenium pageobject

Tags: ruby, selenium, drag-and-drop, page-object-gem

I’m getting:

```
expected Selenium::WebDriver::Element, got 
Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f868ed0ebfed50b04 id="0.38447149586863816-80">:PageObject::Elements::Div (TypeError)
```

Error when I try to drag and drop a column on a web page

This is how I define my pageobject (it's an array of column headers):

```
divs(:column_main_titles, class: 'column__header')
```

this is my code:

```
def test_drag_and_drop
  source = column_main_titles_elements[0]
  target = column_main_titles_elements[1]
  @browser.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform
end
```

could someone please tell me what I did wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `column_main_titles_elements` is from a page object method, you need to get the underlying selenium elements, which can be done with the `element` method.

Try:

```
def test_drag_and_drop
  source = column_main_titles_elements[0].element
  target = column_main_titles_elements[1].element
  @browser.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform
end
```